# yet another issue with call by value|reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

The question is simple and may has been discussed before, but I could find a clear answer for my case. Assume I pass a pointer object to a function

```
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
   foo * aFoo = new foo;
   bar(aFoo);
   delete aFoo;
   aFoo = NULL;
   return 0;
}
```

Then the function is written like this

```
void bar (foo *f)
{
  f->insert();
}
```

The question:

Is that a `call by value` or `call by reference`? I know in call by value, there is an overhead for copying the object from main() to bar(). So I want to be sure that is a `call by reference`.

Comment: Aside from your question: Why are you dynamically allocating (and never deleting `aFoo`? `foo aFoo bar(&aFoo)` would have been less problematic

Comment: So why exactly do you allocate `aFoo` dynamically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a call by value, where the value *of the pointer* `aFoo` is being copied into the function parameter `f`.

A call *by reference* is a call where the parameter is a reference, and side-effects *on the argument* (and not on objects possibly pointed to by that argument) which occur inside the function are visible to the caller when the function returns.

So for instance this is a function accepting a parameter by reference:

```
void bar(foo*& f)
//           ^
//           Here you are taking a pointer by reference
```

While this is a function accepting a parameter by value:

```
void bar(foo* f)
//          ^
//          Here you are taking a pointer to foo by value
```

You are probably puzzled by the fact that taking a `foo` by reference and writing:

```
void bar(foo& f)
{
    f.insert();
}
```

Has pretty much the same effect as passing a *pointer* to the same `foo` object by value and writing:

```
void bar(foo* f)
{ // Precondition: f != nullptr
    f->insert();
}
```

However, the two things are conceptually different. While the value/state of the object you passed in the first case can be different when the function returns from the value/state it had before calling the function, in the second case the value *of the pointer* you provided will be the same as it was before you called `bar()` - while the object *pointed to* may have undergone some state change.

Also notice, that a pointer can be null, while a reference is always bound to an object.

Comment: With the second one, then I cannot use "f->insert()". Right?

Comment: No but `f.insert()`. You must call bar like this in your example to use call by reference: `bar(*aFoo);`.

Comment: @mahmood: No, you have to use `f.insert()`. The important thing is to notice that when you pass an argument by reference your argument can be modified inside the function, and it may have a different value when the function returns than it had before you called it. Notice, that I mean the argument itself, and not the object pointed to by the argument. If you pass a pointer by value and the pointer points to a certain object `x1`, it will still point to `x1` after the function returns, because the function (whatever it did) worked with a *copy* of that pointer

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it is `call by value` in terms of the pointer to Foo formally.  But since you pass a pointer to a function instead of the class instance itself, then it is *conceptually* call by reference in terms of the class instance since the function call does not copy the whole instance but just its pointer.

```
Foo fooInstance;
// providing a way to point (less formally you can call it refer) to the instance
Foo* fooPointer = &fooInstance;

// this function call is call by value (passing the value of the pointer).
// but you can logically view it as 'call by reference' to fooInstance.
bar(fooPointer);
```